# mysql working with very big and growing table

Tags: partitioning, mysql

I have a table that is growing daily and becoming very big very quickly.
How can i handle this kind of data.
can i partition the table, and if so how?
here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `checks` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `environment` char(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `CheckName` char(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `CheckDate` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `SeverityNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `SysName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `SysType` text NOT NULL,
  `ResultTable` varchar(18000) NOT NULL,
  `maxSeverety` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `appl_code` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `appl_model` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CheckMax` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `elapsed` decimal(20,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cpu` decimal(20,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `manual` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `closedBy` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `closedDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `CheckGroup` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateInt` int(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`dateInt`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Index 2` (`SeverityNumber`,`CheckName`,`CheckDate`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Index 1` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='OwaspAvilability\r\n';
```

any ideas??

Comment: what "very big" and "very quickly" means for you? Gigabytes? Terabytes? What do you mean by partinioning the table? Note that your question could better fit on stackoverflow as it's more about programming than general use of computers. But before posting it there, please make sure you make it more specific

Comment: Yes you are right. the table contain about 40000 recorde after about a month and it is supposed to continue working like that on and on. Partitioning means cutting the table to smaller pieces using mysql tools How do i move the question to stackoverflow.